# How can I declare the type of a function defined within a let

Tags: haskell, typechecking, nested-function

I want to write something like:

```
f :: (a -> b) -> a -> c -> b
f g =
   let inner :: a -> c -> b
       inner x y = g x
   in inner
```

but this gives me an error.because it doesn't recognize that I'm trying to refer to the same "a" and "b" types as in the declaration as f

How can I explicitly give the proper type for inner?

Comment: You'll need the extension `ScopedTypeVariables`, and you will probably also need to add an explicit `forall a b c .` to your signature.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables

Comment: In this particular case you don't actually need the inner type signature, and you could even opt to write your function in the form `f g = const . g` (or even `f = (const .)`) to get the same behavior.  You don't even need the outer type signature, GHC correctly infers it with `const . g`.

Comment: @bheklilr, type signatures are good documentation. If the programmer in question thinks having one helps clarify things, then that's a good reason to put one in.

Comment: @dfeuer Certainly, I always put type signatures on top level functions in my code, but my point here was that a type signature at all is unnecessary to get this code to compile.  ScopedTypeVariables is unnecessary since the compiler can infer the type completely from the definition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need the extension [`ScopedTypeVariables`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables). You also need to add an explicit `forall a b c .` to your signature, which signals to bind the variables for the whole scope of the definition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall a b c . (a -> b) -> a -> c -> b
f g =
   let inner :: a -> c -> b
       inner x y = g x
   in inner
```

Comment: @luqui Thanks for that, I wasn't really sure why it was necessary!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this would be to bind the outer and inner types by making g a parameter in inner, like this....

```
f g =
   let inner :: (a->b)->a -> c -> b
       inner g x y = g x
   in inner g
```

This does change your structure slightly though....  And possibly negates the reason to have an inner let in the first place, but in many cases (depending on the larger program) this might help.